# How to test Apple Pay using TSYS SDK in sandbox mode?

Tags: ios, applepay

1) Can I test the Apple Pay integration using TSYS SDK in sandbox mode using the actual card from Passbook pointing to TSYS sandbox mode.

2) Is there any way to add dummy test credit card in Passbook, so that I can test using that dummy card. I hope Apple does not permit this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. This will process against TSYS' staging environment and won't actually capture funds.
2. Unfortunately no, you will need to add a real, live card in Passbook. This shouldn't really matter in the end per 1. since funds aren't captured though. There is no way to bypass' iOS' card activation system.

Comment: Can you please help me how you managed to integarte TSYS for Apple Pay ?